# How to write a non-trivial function that returns a function in Scala?

Tags: scala

In Javascript, I would write a higher order function returning another function this way:

```
var f = function(x) {
  return function(y) {
    // something using x and y
  }
}
```

The Scala syntax for this seems to be:

```
def f(x: Any)(y: Any) = // Something with x and y
```

which is fine if you never need to do anything before creating the returned function.  But suppose you had to process x somehow before creating the return function (example again in Javascript):

```
var f = function(x) {
  // Something using x
  return function(y) {
    // something using y based on the above logic
  }
}
```

The [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html) is unclear on this point.

Comment: The syntax you mentioned is for methods. Check lambdas instead: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Was not aware the syntax is different for methods vs. functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, calling the following function:

```
def hof(i:Int) = (x:Int) => x + i
```

returns a `Int => Int` function, that is one that will take an `Int` and return an `Int`. For your case you can do like:

```
 def hof(i:Int) = {
    // do some other stuff....

   (x:Int) => i + x  //the last statement, so this function will be returned. 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expliclty return a function instead of using separate parameter lists e.g.

```
def f(x: Any) = {
    //something using x
    (y: Any) => //something with x and y
}
```

or

```
val f: (Any => (Any => Any)) = x => {
    //something using x
    y => //something with x and y
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really answering the question.  I'm looking for how to execute some logic within the initial call before constructing the return function.

Comment: Is worth commenting that the second version will execute `something using x` everytime the returned function is called, as opposed to your first version that will only execute it once.

Comment: @Chirlo - No, that won't happen `val g = f("x"); g(123); g(456)` will only execute any effects in `f` once.

Comment: You're very right, the x lambda of course returns the y lambda and not the whole `{}` block!

Answer (score 1):

As @Chirlo said, `Int => Int` denotes a function .

`A => B` is just syntactic sugar for the trait `FunctionN[A,B]` where

- `A` is the **input** type
- `B` the **output** type
- `FunctionN` varies according to the number of inputs : [Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1) accepts 1 input, [Function2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function2) accepts 2 inputs...

So using Chirlo's example,

```
def hof(i:Int) = {
    // do some other stuff....

   (x:Int) => i + x  //the last statement, so this function will be returned. 
 }
```

, this is equivalent to

```
def hof = new Function1[Int,Function1[Int,Int]] {   
    def apply(i:Int) = new Function1[Int,Int] {     
        def apply(x:Int) = i + x 
    }
}
```